# Unknown annotations in Azure DevOps Pull Request files tab

Tags: azure-devops, annotations, pull-request

I was reviewing a pull request in our Azure DevOps instance and I noticed that in the Files tab some lines of code were annotated with flags, checkmarks and exclamation marks (see screenshot). I wasn't able to figure out what they mean. Hovering over them didn't display a hint balloon. Does anyone know?

[image: Azure DevOps annotations]

Comment: Are you using Azure DevOps services or Azure DevOps server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have configured a pipeline that collects and publishes [code coverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-code-coverage-results?view=azure-devops), it posts a code coverage status when a pull request is raised. By default, the server checks for atleast 70% of changed lines being covered by tests.

In the changed files view of a pull request, lines that are changed are also annotated with coverage indicators to show whether those lines are covered. Check [Code coverage for pull requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops) for details.

[image]